# How to update AWS NLB setting to store logs in S3 bucket by k8s annotations

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, annotations, amazon-eks, nlb

I want to configure AWS NLB to store logs at the S3 bucket?
I have:

- AWS EKS cluster (v1.15),
- NLB (created by Nginx controller),
- S3 bucket with AIM (done as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-access-logs.html).

I've added these annotations to my terraform code to nginx ingress:

```
set {
  name  = "controller.service.annotations.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-enabled"
  value = "true"
}
set {
  name  = "controller.service.annotations.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-name"
  value = "nlb-logs-bucket"
}
set {
  name  = "controller.service.annotations.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-prefix"
  value = "/nlblogs"
}
```

I see that annotations are added to the controller, but in AWS console NLB settings didn't change (logs aren't saving to the bucket).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. I hope, it will help anybody.

As I understand, mentioned above annotations are only for ELB, and they don't work for NLB. I tried to update EKS to 1.16 and 1.17. It works for ELB, but not for NLB.

So, the solution is - to use local-exec provision in Terraform for k8s. At least it works for me.

Here is the code:

```
resource "null_resource" "enable_s3_bucket_logging_on_nlb" {
  triggers = { <TRIGGERS> }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOS
for i in $(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --region=<REGION> --names=$(echo ${data.kubernetes_service.nginx_ingress.load_balancer_ingress.0.hostname} |cut -d- -f1) | \
jq ".[][] | { LoadBalancerArn: .LoadBalancerArn }" |awk '{print $2}' |tr -d '"'); do \
aws elbv2 modify-load-balancer-attributes --region=<REGION> --load-balancer-arn $i --attributes Key=access_logs.s3.enabled,Value=true \
Key=access_logs.s3.bucket,Value=nlb-logs-bucket Key=access_logs.s3.prefix,Value=nlblogs;\
done; \
EOS
  }
}
```

where:

- <TRIGGERS> - condition for the trigger
- <REGION> - region of your NLB

Answer (score 1):

I quite like the answer from above - I just modified the terraform code to rely less on any cli processing:

```
data "kubernetes_service" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name      = "${local.k8s_nginx_name}-controller"
    namespace = local.k8s_nginx_namespace
  }
}

locals {
  nlb_hostname = data.kubernetes_service.nginx.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname
  nlb_name     = split("-", local.nlb_hostname)[0]

  # S3 log bucket needs:
  #  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-permissions
  nlb_attributes_json = jsonencode([
    { Key = "deletion_protection.enabled", Value = "true" },
    { Key = "load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled", Value = "true" },
    { Key = "access_logs.s3.enabled", Value = "true" },
    { Key = "access_logs.s3.bucket", Value = var.s3_log_name },
    { Key = "access_logs.s3.prefix", Value = "nlblogs" },
  ])
}

data "aws_lb" "nginx-nlb" {
  name = local.nlb_name
}

resource "null_resource" "enable_s3_bucket_logging_on_nlb" {
  triggers = {
    nlb_arn             = data.aws_lb.nginx-nlb.arn
    nlb_attributes_json = local.nlb_attributes_json
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOS
    aws elbv2 modify-load-balancer-attributes \
      --region=${var.aws_region} \
      --load-balancer-arn ${data.aws_lb.nginx-nlb.arn} \
      --attributes '${local.nlb_attributes_json}'\
    EOS
  }
}
```